# ElasticSearch Index, Update APIs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I have a use-case where I create month based indexes in ElasticSearch. The data in these indexes can be updated (append-only to array type fields) if a document already exists in any month based index or else the document will be created in the current month index.

Can I do this with a single operation (append if exists in any index or else create in latest index)? If not, what is the simplest way of achieving this (using JAVA)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAVA API, try [Rest High Level Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html). You can search the existing document using [GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-get.html) and you can send an [Update Request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update.html) to Elasticsearch. While Updating the existing document, make sure that you have added the existing meta-data in the content. [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-index.html) will be useful for indexing it for the first time.

Once you are familiar with the concepts, instead of sending Update Request, you can directly send Index Request which will be considered as an update request by the Elasticsearch itself.